# FFMPEG - create mp4 from images and apply watermark and zoompan filter

Tags: video, ffmpeg, images

I have a command that takes images and creates an mp4 video with the zoompan filter on each image, applies a watermark over the video, and cross fades between the images:

```
ffmpeg -y -i img-1.jpg -i img-2.jpg -i img-3.jpg -f lavfi -i color=black:r=25:s=1280x720:d=15 -loop 1 -i watermark.png -filter_complex [0:v]setsar=1,setdar=16/9,scale=5120:2880,zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0005,1.1)':x='0':y='0':d=125,format=yuv420p,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[va0];[1:v]setsar=1,setdar=16/9,scale=7680:4320,zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.1,max(1.001,zoom-0.0005))':x='0':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':d=125,format=yuv420p,format=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+5/TB[va1];[2:v]setsar=1,setdar=16/9,scale=5120:2880,zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0005,1.1)':x='5120':y='2880':d=125,format=yuv420p,format=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+10/TB[va2];[3:v][va0]overlay[over1];[over1][va1]overlay[over2];[over2][va2]overlay[over3];[over3][4:v]overlay=W-w:H-h:shortest=1,fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=t=out:st=14.5:d=0.5,format=yuv420p[outv] -c:v libx264 -map [outv] -s 1280x720 -aspect 16:9 -r 25 -crf 18 -preset ultrafast output.mp4
```

Output:

```
ffmpeg version 2.6.8 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --optflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfaac --enable-nonfree --disable-indev=jack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-openal --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      54. 20.100 / 54. 20.100
  libavcodec     56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavformat    56. 25.101 / 56. 25.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 11.102 /  5. 11.102
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[mjpeg @ 0x1d78dc0] Changeing bps to 8
Input #0, image2, from 'img-1.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 25016 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 940x749 [SAR 1:1 DAR 940:749], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[mjpeg @ 0x1d7b660] Changeing bps to 8
Input #1, image2, from 'img-2.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 35632 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 962x642 [SAR 150:150 DAR 481:321], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[mjpeg @ 0x1d7c540] Changeing bps to 8
Input #2, image2, from 'img-3.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 20180 kb/s
    Stream #2:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 750x500 [SAR 100:100 DAR 3:2], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #3, lavfi, from 'color=black:r=25:s=1280x720:d=15':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #3:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #4, png_pipe, from 'watermark.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #4:0: Video: png, rgba, 1280x720 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[swscaler @ 0x1d27220] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x247af80] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x250e260] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[libx264 @ 0x24576e0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x24576e0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x24576e0] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x24576e0] 264 - core 142 r2438 af8e768 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=18.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.25.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.26.100 libx264
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (mjpeg) -> setsar
  Stream #1:0 (mjpeg) -> setsar
  Stream #2:0 (mjpeg) -> setsar
  Stream #3:0 (rawvideo) -> overlay:main
  Stream #4:0 (png) -> overlay:overlay
  format -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[Parsed_overlay_22 @ 0x24544e0] [framesync @ 0x24553e8] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.
    Last message repeated 58 times
[Parsed_overlay_23 @ 0x1fac660] [framesync @ 0x24559e8] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.
    Last message repeated 59 times
[swscaler @ 0x6962820] Warning: data is not aligned! This can lead to a speedloss
[Parsed_overlay_24 @ 0x1faedc0] [framesync @ 0x2456008] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.
    Last message repeated 59 times
frame=  375 fps= 24 q=-1.0 Lsize=   15650kB time=00:00:15.00 bitrate=8547.0kbits/s    
video:15648kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.015783%
[libx264 @ 0x24576e0] frame I:2     Avg QP:10.50  size:196471
[libx264 @ 0x24576e0] frame P:373   Avg QP:13.66  size: 41902
[libx264 @ 0x24576e0] mb I  I16..4: 100.0%  0.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x24576e0] mb P  I16..4:  7.9%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4: 53.6%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:38.5%
[libx264 @ 0x24576e0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 74.5% 63.6% 36.4% inter: 37.1% 23.4% 8.1%
[libx264 @ 0x24576e0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 39% 44% 11%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x24576e0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 29% 37% 27%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x24576e0] kb/s:8545.37
```

Every part of this command is working as expected except for the duration of the zoompan filter. With this video at 25 fps and the duration of the zoompan filters specified at 125 frames, the zoompan filter should last the entire 5 seconds of each image. But, it is only lasting about 2 seconds and then stopping. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ffmpeg` is too old. Users are recommended to use a build from the current git master branch. You can [download](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) or [compile](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos) a recent version.

Comment: Yep, that was it. Downloaded pre-built binary from your link with version 3.1.4 and it worked.